# listview having 2 buttons and text in every row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

Im new to android development. I want to put 2 buttons to the rows of the list view. I added a text and centerd it but when i add a image button it doesnt run well. can you help me pls.this is the layout for   listview row and this working .I want to add to buttons to this

listviviItems.XML

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/listView12"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="hello" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on, " it doesnt run well"?

Comment: post your all layout plz.

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper layout. 
If you want more than one view in every row, you need to take a viewgroup as root view and desired views as its children

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_comment_frame"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_comment_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_comment_frame"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_comment_photo"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_comment_commenttext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_comment_username"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_comment_photo"
    android:text="comment text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```